# how to get IP address of all virtual machines running on hyper V

Tags: ip-address, powershell-3.0, hyper-v

is there any way to get IP addresses of all running Virtual machines with PowerShell? I have tried the following

```
Get-VM | ?{$_.State -eq "Running"} | Select -ExpandProperty networkadapters

Get-VM | ?{$_.State -eq "Running"} | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Select VMName, IPAddresses
```

I am able to get list of virtual machines but I'm not getting any IP addresses for them

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's an answer to your question by the Ed Wilson, "The Scripting Guy" here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/04/24/use-powershell-to-get-name-and-ip-address-of-virtual-machines/

Adapting it to your case:

```
get-vm | ?{$_.State -eq "Running"} | select -ExpandProperty networkadapters | select vmname, macaddress, switchname, ipaddresses | ft -wrap -autosize
```

I hope this is still useful.

Comment: This requires Integration services to be installed. I didn't have much luck getting integration services to work PROPERLY (not being degraded) on Linux guests.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on a CentOS 7 (minimal) Linux hyper-v guest.  "ip addr show" seems to work from the Linux console.

Comment: The arp -a trick from the answer below works for Linux guests. Combined with MAC address matching, it works.

Answer (score 20):

In either PowerShell or Windows Batch, you can use `arp -a` to list IP addresses of everything on your Windows machine (both real and Hyper-V machines are listed). You can filter on Mac address to get precisely the IP you're looking for.

```
arp -a | findstr 00-15-5d-19-73-00
  172.17.210.62         00-15-5d-19-73-00     static
```

Comment: Clever.  on PowerShell, you can also do e.g. `Get-NetNeighbor -LinkLayerAddress 00-15-5d-*` (the wildcard works, or of course you can just put the whole MAC in)